# How do I sort a nested array alphabetically without affecting the order of the outer array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, vue.js

I have an array of objects titled "Inventory". Each inventory object has an order property which I am sorting numerically in ascending order. Within each inventory object is an array of vehicles. And within this array exists a model property which is also an array.

```
    inventory: [
     {
       category: American,
       order: 1,
       vehicles: [
        {
          instock: 'yes',
          model: [
             {
               lang: 'en-US'
               title: 'mustang'
             }
          ]
        }
     ],
     [
        {
          instock: 'no',
          model: [
             {
               lang: 'en-US'
               title: 'viper'
             }
          ]
        }
     ],
     [
        {
          instock: 'yes',
          model: [
             {
               lang: 'en-US'
               title: 'camaro'
             }
          ]
        }
     ]


    }
   ]
```

I am trying to write a method that keeps the overall sorting of the inventory array based on 'order' but sorts the 'vehicles' array based on the alphabetical order of the 'title' property within the model array.

So far I have this method which only sorts the order of the 'inventory' objects. I'm not sure if I can somehow chain an addition sort method which then sorts the vehicles array.

```
 const sortedInventory = inventory.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.order < b.order) return -1;
        if (a.order > b.order) return 1;
        return 0;
      })
```

Comment: `inventory.vehicles.sort(someFunction)`, it's exactly the same and that will have no effect on the outer array.

Comment: Do I chain another sort method and drill down the the appropriate array? An example would help.

Comment: The `vehicles` arrays are completely independent of the outer array; you'll have to iterate through each `inventory` object and sort the `vehicles` arrays one by one; you can't sort all of them at the same time. It may be that I'm not understanding what you want to do.

Comment: Yes this is what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: Can you add how expected result should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through your inventory list and sort vehicles for each inventory without affecting the initial order of the inventories;

**Update**
Answer editted per OP's comment.

```
for (const inv of inventory) {
     inv.vehicles.sort((a, b) => { 
             if (a.model[0].title < b.model[0].title) return 1;
             if (a.model[0].title > b.model[0].title) return -1;
             return 0;
         });
}
```

Comment: I'm actually not trying to sort the models array. I'm trying to sort the vehicles array based on the alphabetical order of the title. IE vehicle[i].model[0].title.. With my data, there's always only one object in the model array. However there can be multiple objects in the vehicle array.

Comment: getting '[object Object] is not iterable' w/ this solution

Comment: @LDB your JSON seems to be faulty. For instance, an array opens at line 16 which is not a property of the inventory object. Make sure `inventory` is a proper list of inventory objects and the code above should work just fine

Comment: Thx. I meant to edit my last comment. This solution works and I have accepted the answer.